# Bring Div before Img in html using css

Tags: css

I am not able to display div text before image, this is what i want

[image]

But not able to get it right.

#### html

```
<div id="Header" class="header-first">
     <h2 class="sometext">Fruit</h2>

    <div id="number-of-fruits" style="display: inline; float: right;">0</div> <span>
        <img id="someImage" src="http://www.journeys.travel/images/familytrips/iconCollapseArrow.gif" class="someimage">
     </span>

</div>
```

#### css

```
.header-first {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
}
.sometext {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px 4px;
    text-align: left!important;
    color: blue;
}
.someimage {
    float: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/WyPWs/1/

Comment: try putting the arrow first in the markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/WyPWs/4/

Try wrapping your right hand side content in a single div, and then treat your items separately.

```
    <div class="right-section">
        <span class="number">0</span>
        <img src="http://www.journeys.travel/images/familytrips/iconCollapseArrow.gif" class="my-image">
    </div>
```

Comment: This is the preferred way but my method is quicker

Comment: @httpgio I would say they are equally quick, but as you say, this is preferred, as the markup now makes more sense ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use positioning. In this case I used relative positioning.

```css
#number-of-fruits {
    position:relative;
    right:30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WyPWs/10/